# Android Studio Unable to Start Activity, Cannot cast to android.view.View$OnClickListener

Tags: android, view, casting, onclick, onclicklistener

We are working on creating a basic app in my online class and I keep running into this issue where the Instructions have us type a method with an @Override for an onClick. I was able to get one of the methods to work with an autofill help from A.S. itself but this next one won't fix itself out. I have run into other issues over this class as well and I know the Instructions are a few years old. Possibly out of date now?

I'm pretty new to Android Java and coding overall. It seems that the app is trying to use the onClick method incorrectly. I will post the whole class I'm working with because I'm not sure where the problem is exactly.

```
package com.test.firstandroidapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class InformationPageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnSave;
    Spinner spnSeason;
    SeekBar skbTemp;
    TextView lblSeekValue;
    Switch swchAllergy;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_information_page);

        spnSeason = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnSeason);
        skbTemp = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.skbTemp);
        swchAllergy = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.swchAllergy);
        lblSeekValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblSeekValue);
        btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);

        btnSave.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);

        skbTemp.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                String display = String.valueOf(progress);
                lblSeekValue.setText(display);
            }
            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }
        });

    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String season, allergies;
        int temperature;
        season = spnSeason.getSelectedItem().toString();
        temperature=skbTemp.getProgress();
        allergies = (String) (swchAllergy.isChecked() ? swchAllergy.getTextOn() : swchAllergy.getTextOff()); //if the switch is on then the user has allergies
        Intent intent = new Intent(InformationPageActivity.this, InformationResultsActivity.class); //pass information to the results activity
        intent.putExtra("season", season);
        intent.putExtra("temperature", temperature);
        intent.putExtra("allergies", allergies);
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

And here is the Main Menu Class parts that go to the view i'm trying to have opened, The onclicklistener is inside the onCreate method and the goInfo is it's own method

```
            Button btnInfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnInfo);
        btnInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                       @Override
                                       public void onClick(View v) {
                                           goInfo();
                                       }
                                   }
        );
    }

    private void goInfo() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenuActivity.this, InformationPageActivity.class);
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the issue. I needed to add an implements statement to the class for the onclicklistener. I'm answering my own question in case someone in the future has the same error. Here is what I did.

My problematic class was

```
public class InformationPageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
```

This was causing the error "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.firstandroidapp/com.test.firstandroidapp.InformationPageActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.test.firstandroidapp.InformationPageActivity cannot be cast to android.view.View$OnClickListener"

I solved the issue by fixing the class adding the implements

```
public class InformationPageActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
```